# Jpa repository findBy method signature with multiple or operators?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I have Entity class for Product like this:

```
@Entity
public class Product {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer ID_product;

  @NotNull
  private String prodName;

  @NotNull
  private String prodDesc;

  @NotNull
  private Integer price;

  @NotNull
  private String prodBrand;

  @NotNull
  private String prodImage;

  @ManyToOne
  private Category category;
```

I want to make the controller look like this:

```
List<Product> productList = productRepository.findByProdNameOrProdBrandContains(search);
model.addAttribute("products" , productList);
```

How do I wrote findBy methods in my Repository if i want to search the keyword of prodName OR prodBrand? I'm imagining something like this:

```
List<Product> findByProdNameOrProdBrand(String prodName || String prodBrand);
```

Do I have to create different function/ model or something, and if so, how can i use both fucntion/ model in my thymeleaf? Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the following method in repository:

```
List<Product> findByProdNameOrProdBrand(String prodName, String prodBrand);
```

But I suggest you to switch to `Sepcification<T>` when query with more than 3 conditions.

Comment: But won't that take 2 inputs from user?

Comment: So your question would be: `How can I find by dynamic condition`, right?

Comment: For more than 3 conditions, you should read about `Query DSL` and `Specification`. There you can use multiple condition in one function depends on your input